# Bootstrap flex making the div overflow

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am using Bootstrap 4. I am facing an odd issue. I am adding the html using the jquery. The div has call .col-md-9 d-flex. When the other div's are appened to main div (under parent col-md-9) one it overflows and takes whole page (width) and over ride the other div (col-md-3). The code is given as

```
<div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-9 filters-div d-flex"><!-- the dynamic code will append to this div-->
                         <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">      
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Date and time range:</label>

                              <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-clock"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" id="reservationdate" class="form-control float-right datetimepicker-input" data-toggle="datetimepicker" data-target="#reservationdate">
                              </div>
                              <!-- /.input group -->
                            </div>
                          <!-- /.form group -->
                          </div> 
                          
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
                      <div class="my-div">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default">
                              <i class="fas fa-filter"></i>Add Filters
                            </a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary close-result">Cancel</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success get-result">Submit</a>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

The jquery which produces the dom element is as follows

```
$(document).delegate(".add-filter","click",function(){
    $val=$("#filter-add").val();
    $text=$('#filter-add option:selected').text();
  $new_text=$text.replace(/ /g, "-");

    $html="<div class='col-md-2 col-xs-6 delete-all' id='"+$new_text+"'><div class='form-group'>";
    $html+="<label>"+$text+":</label>";
    $html+="<div class='input-group'>";
    $html+="<input type='text' class='form-control float-right'><div class='input-group-prepend'><span class='input-group-text delete-filter' data-text='"+$text+"' data-value='"+$val+"'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></span> </div></div>";
    $html+="</div></div>";

    $(".filters-div").append($html);
    $("#filter-add option:selected").remove();
    $('#filter-add').prop('selectedIndex',0);

});
```

Do let me know whats the issue. The example is [here](https://www.callsexchange.net)

**UPDATE:**

The screenshot is attached as follows

[image]

Comment: Which element is overflowing specifically?

Comment: the one which are added dynamically from jquery. When you add them.

Comment: @kb_ you can try the link if you add filter more than 5 you will see the issue.

Comment: @kb_ i have added the screenshot as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **flex-wrap** to your div:

```
<div class="col-md-9 filters-div d-flex flex-wrap"><!-- the dynamic code will append to this div-->
```

Instead, if you don't want to wrap you can reduce the **max-width** of col-md-2:

```
.col-md-2 {
    max-width: 12% !important;
}
```

Your issue is up to col-md-2: when you have much of them you get the problem.